# In the last Harry Potter book, who kills these two characters?

Tags: harry-potter

I have always wondered this, and as today is the anniversary of the battle of Hogwarts, I think I will ask this:

> Who killed Tonks and Lupin in the battle of Hogwarts?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Antonin Dolohov and Bellatrix Lestrange

Rowling answered this in a [2007 livechat on Bloomsbury.com](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html):

> **J.K. Rowling:** Remus was killed by Dolohov and Tonks by Bellatrix.

Comment: F---ing Bellatrix, eh? Always killing people.

Comment: WHYYYYYYY!!!! Anyone but Bellatrix!

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'd be interested to see a statistical breakdown of who killed who; I feel like Bella tends to come up a lot more often than anyone else in these sorts of questions

Comment: @Jason This might be a good start: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_deaths (strangely, it only credits her with 3 deaths...)

Comment: I'm surprised Molly was able to kill Bellatrix so easily when Tonks had so much trouble.

Comment: So, if Harry, Heromine and Ron had killed Dolohov in the diner instead of stunned/erased his memory...Remus would be alive!! Silly children and their sentiment on life.

Comment: Spoiler markdown might be a good idea here.  Unfortunately that's not a 6 char change, so can't edit it myself.

Comment: @Mayshar That's exactly the type of thinking a Slytherin would have!

Comment: @TylerH: One, while fighting Tonks Bellatrix was most likely fully focussed, aware of Tonks' training and reputation. Molly, on the other hand? Bellatrix even taunted her, obviously not taking her seriously. -- Two, Molly chose to be a housewife and mother, for love. What do we know of her spellcasting prowess? -- Three, remember what we learned about *crucio*? You must **want** to cause hurt for it to be effective, so attitude obviously influences your spellcasting. Molly, defending her only daughter? Bellatrix underestimated the protectiveness and wrath of a mother. Bad, *bad* mistake.

Comment: Why deos JKR feel the need to give us more information than what she put in the books? I don't trust that the post-book information is something that was "planned"; she may just think of something that fits. If you can't write a self-consistent book series, then don't try to fix it afterwards. Let us have our open questions. I find it all riddikulus.

Comment: @Michael - Yeah, killing really wasn't her thing.  Usually she preferred to just torture people to the brink of insanity instead (e.g. the Longbottoms).

Comment: @adamdc78 Spoiler marks in the question are kind of pointless with all the spoilers in the comments.

Comment: @AndersMB Exactly. I also find it funny that JKR needs to write a whole site after the books. Just a "these are the books, consider them canon and feel free to speculate" would have been enough.

Comment: Remus' killer is also reported on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/remus-lupin).